# Jung Jar file support generic

Tags: java, jar, jung

I add jung jar file but my PageRankCalc class still doesn't accept generic

```
 DirectedGraph<Integer, String> g =  new DirectedSparseGraph<Integer, String>();
```

(The type DirectedSparseGraph is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments )

i test alot of jung jar files but no one support generic .. can any one help me

Comment: What version of JUNG are you using?  It sounds like it's pre-2.0, which is when generics were added.

Comment: I test jung-api-2.0 , jung-api-2.0-sources & jung-api-2.0-tests but no one support generics.

Comment: I don't know what your "PageRankCalc" class might be including, but I guarantee that the JUNG DirectedSparseGraph class, as of v2.0, supports generics.  My guess is that you have some previous version of JUNG in your classpath.